# Как в одной картинке вывести несколько графиков по классам?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, seaborn

Загружаю данные из датасета `iris`:

```
from sklearn import datasets
data = datasets.load_iris(return_X_y=False)
X = data.data
y = data.target
names = data.target_names
```

Датафрейм со всеми данными и целевой переменной в `y`:

```
dfy = pd.DataFrame(y)
df = pd.DataFrame(X)
dfy = dfy.rename(columns={0: 'y'})
df_ = pd.concat([df,dfy], axis = 1)

sns.pairplot(df_, hue = 'y')
```

Несколько боксплотов в одной картинке без классов выводится:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(14,7))
sns.boxplot(data=df_.drop(['y'], axis=1), palette=sns.color_palette('Greens'))
plt.show()
```

А несколько бохплотов с классами из столбца `y` смогла вывести только так:

```
for i in range(4):
        sns.boxplot(data=df_, x ='y', y = i, hue='y')
        plt.show()
```

Как вывести несколько бохплотов с классами в одной картинке?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
df = (pd.DataFrame(
         data.data, 
         columns=data.feature_names)
        .assign(target=data.target))

d = (df.set_index("target")
       .stack()
       .reset_index(name="val")
       .rename(columns={"level_1":"feature"}))

sns.boxplot(x="feature", y="val", hue="target", data=d)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

или так:

```
sns.boxplot(x="feature", y="val", data=d)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]